# Shorten JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I got some help a few weeks ago on some code for a drop down menu but I am wondering if it is possible to make the code shorter because the current code shown below is quite big, any help would be great.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#zone-bar li em").mouseenter(function() {
   var hidden = $(this).parents("li").children("ul").is(":hidden");

   $("#zone-bar>ul>li>ul").hide()        
   $("#zone-bar>ul>li>a").removeClass();

   if (hidden) {
       $(this).parents("li").children("ul").toggle()
              .parents("li").children("a").addClass("zoneCur");
   } 
});

$("#zone-bar>ul>li>ul").mouseleave(function() {
   var hidden = $(this).parents("li").children("ul").is(":hidden");

   $("#zone-bar>ul>li>ul").hide()        
   $("#zone-bar>ul>li>a").removeClass();

   if (visable) {
       $(this).parents("li").children("ul").toggle()
              .parents("li").children("a").addClass("zoneCur");
   } 
});
        });
```

Comment: Are we talking about minifying before sending it to the user, or simplifying for your own sake?

Comment: I could see refactoring it, so that the functionality could be re-used... I don't see any reason to try and shorten it for shortness sake, however.  It is not big.

Comment: @Matchu He means refactoring, but minifying is a good thing to do after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, this can be done using only CSS. Check out [github](http://github.com/jquery/jquery) The menus "switch branch" and "switch tags" are done using CSS only. Another option would be using a [JS minifier](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+minifier)

Comment: Note that because IE's CSS support is broken for older versions, you might still need some scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Here are [38 ways to create a drop-down menu with jQuery](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/).